# Why does STL `set` core dump on find() & empty()?

Tags: c++, stl, coredump

when i want to reach STL lib set::find or empty()... i got core file.

i m using  gcc version 4.1.2 20070115 (prerelease) (SUSE Linux), please see the stack flow:

```
#0  0x00002aaaae7caf2a in _STL::_Rb_tree<unsigned int, unsigned int,
_STL::_Identity<unsigned int>, _STL::less<unsigned int>,
_STL::allocator<unsigned int> >::empty (this=0x8)
    at /home/irish/nagrun/add-ons/include/stlport/stl/_tree.h:370
#1  0x00002aaaae7caf4f in _STL::set<unsigned int, _STL::less<unsigned int>, _STL::allocator<unsigned int> >::empty (this=0x8)
    at /home/irish/nagrun/add-ons/include/stlport/stl/_set.h:129
#2  0x00002aaaae7ca5d1 in User::deleteSessionID (this=0x0, sessionID=4143972353)
    at /home/irish/nagrun/NIG_SRC/PresenceEx_V100R001C41B010/Extends/UserManager/User.cpp:60
```

how can this be possible ?
i can insert into set and traverse inside it with iterators.

Comment: Perhaps your program invokes undefined behaviour? You should present the code which reproduces the problem. Just a crash is often a sign that there is a bug somewhere else in your program.

Comment: How can anyone help you without seeing the code?

Comment: `this=0x8` & `this=0x0` confuse me. Do you access your set by pointer?

Comment: You are apparently doing things with a NULL pointer to a User object.

Comment: I guess this is one of those questions where its a must to provide some code.

Comment: You are calling `User::deleteSessionID()` using a null pointer. By looking further up the call stack, you should be able to find which line of your code is doing this, and then figure out how it came to have a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You were correct in the comments: I have been calling functions on `User` through a null pointer.

I didn't realise this because the stack trace starts deep within the standard library functions, leading me to believe that the problem was with `find`, rather than with how I was calling it.